# Trouble getting recordset to work in an if statement

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am currently using a recordset to get the results from a query I built. From there, I need to compare the values of a report to the results in the recordset so it will highlight the values that match the recordset and the report.

```
lngRed = RGB(255, 0, 0)
 lngBlack = RGB(0, 0, 0)
 lngYellow = RGB(255, 255, 0)
 lngWhite = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strQuery As String

    strQuery = "SELECT qry_Revision_History_Conversions_MaxR.Step_Int " _
    & "FROM qry_Revision_History_Conversions_MaxR " _
    & "Where (((qry_Revision_History_Conversions_MaxR.Step_Int) Is Not Null));"



    If strQuery = Reports![rpt_WI_BOOK]![qry_Select_Step_Filter_Task].Report![Step] Then
[Reports]![rpt_WI_BOOK]![qry_Select_Step_Filter_Task].Report![Step].BackColor = lngYellow
Else
[Reports]![rpt_WI_BOOK]![qry_Select_Step_Filter_Task].Report![Step].BackColor = lngWhite

End If
```

For testing, the results of the query will be a field called Step_Int, and it can have one entry or multiple entries. For an example, I run the report for one process, the query will list three values, 1, 4, and 6 and the report has 13 steps. In this report, steps 1, 4, and 6 should change to yellow. This is not working, I'm not sure if it's how I'm doing the recordset or how I'm using it to compare the results to the report.

Comment: You're not even opening a recordset. You compare the SELECT string with a report field - that makes no sense. Perhaps you have removed to much from the posted code? In which event runs this code?

Answer (score 0):

your strQuery is only a string with a select query on it, you're not supposed to compare it to anything really...

please check this link: http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Recordsets_for_Beginners
it's a small tutorial on how to use recordsets.

basically put, you first build a query:

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT [column] FROM [Table]"
```

then create a recordset.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
```

then you "bind" the record-set to the results of the query.

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

now at this point, we have a recordset named 'rs' with the results of the query (assuming the query is correct and the data in it is valid).

we can go through the results via a loop:

```
If rs.Recordcount <> 0 Then
   MsgBox( rs![column] & "" )
End If
```

When done, you are advised to handle the disposing of the references to free up your resources. although on newer version of Data Objects (later versions of DAO and ADO) you are not really required to do that.

```
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

*more info on the link i gave you at the top ..